# Display PyTorch model with multiple outputs using torchviz make_dots

Tags: pytorch, graphviz, torchvision

I have a model with multiple outputs, 4 to be exact:

```
 def forward(self, x):
      outputs = []
      for conv, act in zip(self.Convolutions, self.Activations):
           y = conv(x)
           outputs.append(act(y))
      return outputs
```

I wanted to display it using `make_dot` from `torchviz`:

```
 from torchviz import make_dot
 generator = ...
 batch = next(iter(generator))
 input, output = batch["input"].to(device, dtype=torch.float), batch["output"].to(device, dtype=torch.float)
 dot = make_dot(model(input), params=dict(model.named_parameters()))
```

But I get the following error:

```
 File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torchviz/dot.py", line 37, in make_dot
 output_nodes = (var.grad_fn,) if not isinstance(var, tuple) else tuple(v.grad_fn for v in var)
 AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'grad_fn'
```

Obviously a list does not have a `grad_fn` function, but according to [this discussion](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/a-model-with-multiple-outputs/10440), I can return a list of outputs.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Model can return a list, but `make_dot` wants a `Tensor`. If output components have similar shape, I suggest to use `torch.cat` on it.

Comment: Thx. Yes, they do. I'll try.

Comment: It worked, thanks. It's a shame that make_dot is not fully compatible with models.

Comment: Well, `torchviz` is small specialized library, in theory it could search for tensors through standard containers, but should it? Somebody will cast tensor to `numpy` array, losing connection to computational graph, and will wander, why `torchviz` fails. Now it just requires tensor, closing all questions.

Comment: Your answer makes sense, but it's always a limitation. We have to modify models in order to display them.

Comment: Is there any work around of this for models having multiple output components but different shape?